# adobe flash actionscript 3 TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have created a flash document and i get this error

TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/setChildIndex()
    at VersiontwoFlashwebsite_fla::MainTimeline/navOverF()

I do not fully understand it so any help would be great... here is the code in which i believe the error is held...

```
import flash.filters.GlowFilter;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;


var navBtnGlow:GlowFilter = new GlowFilter(0x999999,0.5,0,15,1,2,true,false);
mc_navbar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, navOverF);
mc_navbar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, navOutF);
function navOverF(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.filters = [navBtnGlow];
    mc_navbar.setChildIndex(event.target as MovieClip, 1);
    dropdown.gotoAndStop(mc_navbar.getChildAt(1).name);

}
function navOutF(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.filters = [];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's throwing an error at

```
mc_navbar.setChildIndex(event.target as MovieClip, 1);
```

Because `event.target` isn't a child of `mc_navbar`

You might want to use your debugger to check what event.target is referring to and make sure it's what you think it is.

Comment: When i checked i got this error....

[SWF] C:\Users\Dipam\Desktop\Flash website\V3\Version three Flash website.swf - 14577 bytes after decompression
ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/setChildIndex()
 at VersionthreeFlashwebsite_fla::MainTimeline/navOverF()[VersionthreeFlashwebsite_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:12]